# Transformar inputs serializados em JSON

Tags: javascript, json

Em um datatable existem algumas colunas com inputs. Se clicar no botão de Submit eu faço o serialize dos inputs das linhas que estiverem com checkbox marcado.
O retorno do serialize:

```
'id=1596&inputCodPag=dwad&inputDtPagto=22-03-2018&inputDtMalote=&inputTpPagamento=BB&id=2045&inputCodPag=dwad&inputDtPagto=&inputDtMalote=&inputTpPagamento=SAP'
```

O que quero saber é, como transformar isso em um JSON?
O ideal seria manter na seguinte estrutura:

```
[{id:1596,inputCodPag:dwad,inputDtPagto:'22-03-2018',inputDtMalote:'',inputTpPagamento:'BB'},{id:2045, inputCodPag:'dwad', inputDtPagto:''.inputDtMalote:'',inputTpPagamento:'SAP'}]
```

Obrigado.

Comment: são coisas bem diferentes... que tal começar separando a string com `split("&")`, ler cada valor e montar o objeto?

Answer (score 2):

Creio que não tenha algo nativo para isso, mas você pode usar essa função...

```js
function deparam(query) {
    var pairs, i, keyValuePair, key, value, map = {};
    // remove leading question mark if its there
    if (query.slice(0, 1) === '?') {
        query = query.slice(1);
    }
    if (query !== '') {
        pairs = query.split('&');
        for (i = 0; i < pairs.length; i += 1) {
            keyValuePair = pairs[i].split('=');
            key = decodeURIComponent(keyValuePair[0]);
            value = (keyValuePair.length > 1) ? decodeURIComponent(keyValuePair[1]) : undefined;
            map[key] = value;
        }
    }
    return map;
}

let resul = deparam('id=1596&inputCodPag=dwad&inputDtPagto=22-03-2018&inputDtMalote=&inputTpPagamento=BB&id=2045&inputCodPag=dwad&inputDtPagto=&inputDtMalote=&inputTpPagamento=SAP');

console.log(JSON.stringify(resul));
```

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6992585/jquery-deserialize-form#8918929

Comment: Opa! obrigado pela resposta, isso funciona muito bem!! Só tem uma coisa, como no exemplo que dei, que eu serializei duas linhas da tabela (2 id's), a sua function considerou apenas a última, id=2045. Tem uma forma de deixar essa function mais flexível? No caso sempre será os mesmos campos, mas posso dar o submit em 50 linhas.

Comment: Bom, creio que isso não é possível, pois a chave 'id' vem da propriedade 'name' do campo do formulário, ou seja, é um atributo identificador que não pode se repetir, outra questão é que a função converte para objeto antes de converter para JSON, e um objeto também não aceita 2 chaves iguais... caso a resposta tenha te ajudado, é interessante aceita-la no canto superior esquerdo...